# Unknown Property Error using Custom Controller in Visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have an error with a new Visualforce page I'm creating that takes list from a custom controller I made. It is for a standard objects and the class file compiled just fine. But when I start building the Visualforce page it gives me an error that I can't figure out.

This is the Visual Force Page

```
<apex:page controller="SearchAccountListController">    
    <apex:repeat value="{! acctList}" var="acct">
        <apex:outputLink value="/{!acct.Name}">
        <apex:outputText value="{!acct.Phone}"/><br/>
        </apex:outputLink>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

And the Controller:

```
public class SearchAccountListController {
    public List<Account> getNewAccounts() {    
        List<Account> acctList = [SELECT Name,Phone FROM Account];
        return acctList;
    }
}
```

The class compiles fine, I'm using the Developer Console, so that seems to be okay. But then when I go to save my Visualforce page it gives the following error:

Save error: Unknown property 'Unknown property 'SearchAccountListController.acctList'

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a class-level property `acctList`, you only have a local variable with that name. That name is lost when you leave the function.

From visualforce's point of view you have a getter function and what it returns can be accessed with `{!newAccounts}`.